# Git Push doesn't update even though it says changes have been made

Tags: git, version-control

I am in a very weird situation. I am able to succesfully push my changes to my remote git repo. The only problem is even though it says it successfully uploads the changes, no changes are ever made. Even when I go to my remote repo and do a git status. I will see the file that I change sitting in the "files ready to be committed" section. I do a git diff and nothing happens. I look at the file, and none of my changes are there

### LOCAL SIDE

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Air:hrw2 numerical25$ git add app/controllers/users_controller.php
Anthonys-MacBook-Air:hrw2 numerical25$ git commit -m "new update, should work"
[wk1 888d2f8] new update, should work
 1 file changed, 2060 insertions(+), 1997 deletions(-)
 rewrite app/controllers/users_controller.php (97%)
Anthonys-MacBook-Air:hrw2 numerical25$ git push origin
root@superiorsoftllc.com's password: 
stdin: is not a tty
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 8.24 KiB, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To root@superdupersoft.com:/home/super/public_html/staging/hrw2
   92cb549..888d2f8  wk1 -> wk1
```

### REMOTE SIDE

```
# On branch wk1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/controllers/users_controller.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .htaccess.swp
#   .idea/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So the problem is that I can do everything successfully, yet no changes are made remotely. If I didnt provide enough just let me know. I am not that great with git, but I worked with 2 jobs that used it, so I am not a complete idiot when it comes to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Git would never silently allow you to push to a non-bare repository, i.e. a repository that contains the actual files, not just the git objects. So, apparently, you are not pushing your changes to the *remote side* where you expect them to turn up.

Could you post the output of `git remote -v` (preferably on both the local and remote system), please, so we can see where you are actually pushing the changes to?

(I am aware that I should post this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whoever set up your workflow has set up a staging area that your push is going to - this is normally done to permit code reviews and other QA activities to take place.  You will need to check with the project administrator for how to proceed next.  *If I am correct then someone needs to approve your changes before they make in into the 'blessed' repository.*

This sort of workflow is described in the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) as [Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Dictator-and-Lieutenants-Workflow).

The clue that makes me think this is in the path /home/super/public_html/***staging***/hrw2 this sort of naming is quite common for this sort of workflow.